# firefox https redirect to http issue

Tags: http, firefox, https

we were trying to redirect https to http for all major browsers, IE and Chrome work ok, but firefox is not taking the code and does not show either http://www.company.com or https://www.company.com, the code we have is as follows:

```
If (Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS") = "on") Then
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.company.com/"
Response.End
ElseIf InStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"), "default.asp") > 0 Then
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.company.com"
Response.End
Else
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
End If
```

any idea to get firefox working? for example: https://www.amazon.com and http://www.amazon.com both work on firefox.

Comment: What exactly is the observed behavior in Firefox?  "not taking the code" doesn't exactly describe what actually happens....